# Displaying image in PictureBox from a HTTP response (image/jpeg)

Tags: c#, image, jpeg, content-type

So I need to send a request to a PHP page which returns an image, which can't be read directly using an URL (Well it can, but it technically only contains image data as opposed to a page ending with .jpg )...

Therefore I need to read the image from the response (which returns `Content-Type: image/jpeg` that the page gives me, which directly shows the image data (as when you open an image in notepad - made of symbols.... )

How can I go about converting this image data into a valid image?

I've tried using the bytes from the response to convert those into an image; using this:

```
    private Bitmap ByteToImage(byte[] blob)
    {
        MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream();
        byte[] pData = blob;
        mStream.Write(pData, 0, Convert.ToInt32(pData.Length));
        Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(mStream, false);
        mStream.Dispose();
        return bm;
    }
```

and

```
byte[] imageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(post(imagelink, ""));
```

But that only gave me an ArgumentException.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) , [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [HttpClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx)  to *download* the  image

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    var img = ByteToImage(wc.DownloadData(url));
}
```

Comment: Hm.. This just makes the picturebox invisible (Default image is an error message)

Comment: @Adam see what `wc.DownloadData(url)` returns. Is it really an image or an error message etc. I have no idea what the server returns....

Comment: I tried `Console.WriteLine(wc.DownloadData(imagelink));` But that just printed `System.Byte[]` (Am I doing it wrong? I'm not a very good programmer)

Comment: @Adam I removed `mStream.Dispose();` from your method and used that link `http://i.cdn.turner.com/cnn/.e/img/3.0/global/header/intl/CNNi_Logo.png` , it worked....

Comment: Sigh... It didn't even work with that image for me - Now I just keep getting "Parameter is not valid" and ArgumentException no matter what code I use

Comment: Got it to work, the problem was that I wasn't setting the image inside the `using(){ }` part... Thank you very much for your help, I4V !